# Under what circumstances will Chrome expire a cookie regardless of its server provided date?

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, cookies

I am facing an issue where-in chrome will immediately expire my remember me cookie that I set to expires DateTime.Now.AddDays(15). This works as expected locally and in Production environments. But Chrome has deemed fit to set the expiration to about 10 months back in my QA environment. No other browser has this behavior. I have not had any luck finding this documentation, if it exists.

Comment: How have you determined that Chrome has deemed fit to set the expiration to about 10 months back?

Comment: By clicking the little (i) in the top left corner. It will show x cookies in use and let you inspect them. I also used the debugging tools in chrome to confirm the expires date is set correctly. However I since have noticed that the Date header of the http response was off. I guess I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I hate answering my own question but my issue was resolved primarily using this find https://serverfault.com/questions/217343/date-header-returned-by-iis7-is-wrong?newreg=ee4e72ecdd73473a9a78b389321d0059.
In QA environments the time of the servers would be frequently changed to a future date and that effects the Date header IIS will return.
In connection with the knowledge that Chrome will expire a cookie immediately if the date is in the future.